# Free energy calculation for spin glass with non-random interactions

Tags: statistical-mechanics, spin-models

In the Sherrington–Kirkpatrick model, $$H = \sum_{i,j} J_{ij} {s}_i {s}_j,$$ where $J_{ij}$'s are independent and identically distributed random variables, and in this case, the free energy may be calculated by the replica method. I am wondering whether there are ways or tools to compute the free energy, when $J_{ij}$ is not randomly distributed, but instead, is a deterministic value, depending on $i,j$, for example, $$ J_{ij} = \frac{\sin(\pi a (i-j))}{\pi (i - j)}.$$

Thanks.

Comment: I believe this paper may be of use: https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9406074, where they study a class of deterministic spin-glasses without quench disorder.

Comment: @PeaBrane, Thanks for the reference, but the method used in the reference is about a high-temperature approximation and it breaks down for the low-temperature region, and I am more interested in the low-temperature region.

Answer (score 1):

I think in case of non-random interaction it is incorrect to use the term *glass*. What poses difficulty here is the alternating sign of the interaction, which might be sometimes ferromagnetic and sometimes anti-ferromagnetic. This likely produces some kind of [frustration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_frustration). Another direction to look into is [RKKY interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RKKY_interaction), which also resembles decaying oscillations.

See, e.g., this paper (and reference therein): [*RKKY Interaction and Intrinsic Frustration in Non-Fermi Liquid Metals*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.1447).